# Как в Java посчитать сколько памяти требуется функции?

Tags: java, алгоритм, память

Есть две функции, выполняющие одну и ту же задачу. Одна использует матрицу, другая рекурсия. Как посчитать какая функция эффективнее по памяти?

Comment: В таком общем виде, никак не посчитать.

Comment: задача явно общего типа, и не имеет привязки к конкретной задачи, гугл в помощь